# How would I draw orbitals for specific atoms (with shapes, not diagrams)?

Tags: orbitals

I'm relatively new to chem and I'm learning about orbitals.  I know that they have distinct shapes (s is a sphere, p is a dumbbell, etc.). However, apparently their shapes change when rotated (s changes into a half sphere or is invisible when rotated about the XYZ plane). Why do they do this; and how would you combine the cloud diagrams for specific atoms? For example, Sulfur (1s<sup>2</sup>2s<sup>2</sup>2p<sup>6</sup>3s<sup>2</sup>3p<sup>4</sup>)'s cloud diagram, with orbitals combined. If it's possible, please explain in beginner terms; the internet isn't helping. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: These orbitals shapes are good for hydrogen only. So focus on hydrogen for the time beings. Introductory chemistry textbooks do an injustice by drawing orbitals for other heavier atoms. It is their imagination. May be paste a picture so that readers can provide you with the search terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to mark this as correct?

Comment: This is not an answer, but it was a suggestion. Still you can post a picture? What do you mean by saying that s orbital becomes a half sphere?

Comment: Added! I assume that that's what it looks like, but I may be misinterpreting the diagram

Comment: It is a sphere, they are showing a half slice to show nodes, regions where the probability of finding the electron is zero.

Comment: The Orbitron site has some very good visualizations: https://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/atomic_orbitals/1s/index.html